# Back in time Euler–Maruyama method

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-differential-equations, eulers-method

Given a stochastic differential equation
$$
dX(t) = a(X(t), t) \, dt + b(X(t),t) \, dW(t), \qquad (1)
$$
we can solve it forward in time with Euler–Maruyama scheme for a finite time step $\Delta t$:
$$
X(t+\Delta t) = X(t) + a(X(t), t) \, \Delta t + b(X(t),t) \, N \, \sqrt{\Delta t}, \qquad (2)
$$
with $N$ being normally distributed random number.

But I need to simulate the trajectories of the system not only forward in time from a given state, but I also need to get the history of the system leading to the current state, i.e. I need to solve the sde (1) back in time.

What would be the correct Euler–Maruyama scheme for that? I actually tried solving (2) to get $X(t)$ from known $X(t+\Delta t)$, but my back-in time trajectories seem to eventually diverge to infinities.

Comment: Simulating an SDE forward simulates a diffusion process. Trying to solve it backwards with no further specification is trying to undo entropy, to unmix the mixed. It is not completely impossible, just rather ill-posed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into "backward stochastic differential equations", which is the type of mathematical tool you use to find the history given a fixed terminal condition. The equation you show is forward by nature and it does not make sense even talking about simulating it backwards.